# Acces Controls in GridTemplateColumn (Telerik)

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

Is it possible to access the control that are in the GridTemplateColumn in a RadGrid in an easy way. My solution works with single postbacks per combobox in the RadGrids GridTemplateColumn so i need to acces them all separably.Anyone has an idea how to accomplish this ? I tried FindControl method but i kept on returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Foobar">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true"
               OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
               <asp:ListItem Text="First" Value="1" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Second" Value="2" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Third" Value="3" />
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

protected void DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gridDataItem  = ((Control)sender).BindingContainer as Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem;
    if (gridDataItem != null)
    {
        var hiddenField = gridDataItem.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
    }
}
```